# Ubuntu Jeos like minimal image for server with JRE

Tags: java, aws, ubuntu-minimal

I need to create minimalistic server appliance for running on amazon ec2 (ami). I tried debootstrap. its coming upto 200+ MB  , its same with vmbuilder also. Are there any ways of getting it down to 100MB or less.

I just need it with bare minimum linux os  + JRE. The smaller the size the better.

Any Suggestion

Regards

Comment: You might want to try Gentoo Linux, it's as minimal as you can get.

Answer (score 2):

You could try starting with just the [Ubuntu minimal image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), found here.  Building up from the 10Mb ISO should give you enough flexibility to keep the size down as much as possible.

[Jeos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JeOS) (Just Enough OS) has been discontinued now - it's only available with the old 8.04 version.  [This document](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html), highlighted by Marcello Nuccio in the comments below, demonstrates that Jeos itself is now replaced by a combination of using vmbuilder and the minimal install.  Quote : "With vmbuilder, there is no need to download a JeOS ISO anymore".

Comment: JeOS is not discontinued, [it is no longer available as a CD-ROM ISO for download, but only as an option](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html) either: while installing from the Server Edition ISO; or to be built using Ubuntu's vmbuilder.

Comment: Well now.  That's a great demonstration of how poor the Help WIKI is.  Go here : https://help.ubuntu.com/, type "Jeos" into the search and try to find anything that might suggest Jeos is still an option.

Comment: Refined my answer to summarise my findings.  Thanks for the link Marcello.  If you do that search I mentioned, then click on the "Official" refinement, then your link is the first hit.  Just a shame that the community docs are so misleading.

Answer (score 1):

this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html) provide a idea to solve it. It uses vmbuilder, a python script that enables you to generate your JEOS in cli.